ALM for Power automate flows triggering Desktop flows using Azure DevOps
I have a Power platform solution consisting of a scheduled 'Cloud flow' and 'Power automate desktop flow', the cloud flow does following activities,

Fetches files from SharePoint (SharePoint Connection)
Invokes the Desktop flow (Desktop Connection)

To prepare for Azure DevOps deployment i need to share the above connections with DevOps Service Principal.  I am able to share the SPO connection with Azure DevOps Service Principal, however, it is not possible to share Desktop Connection, because of this the solution deployment is failing.  As per my understanding without sharing the connections it is not possible to automate deployments (i am using connection references in settings file).
How to overcome the above challenges?  Why there is restriction on sharing Desktop connections?
Additional information:  Below is the task used to import the solution,
- task: PowerPlatformImportSolution@2
  displayName: 'importSolution'
  inputs:
   authenticationType: 'PowerPlatformSPN'
   PowerPlatformSPN: ${{ parameters.devOpsSPN }}
   SolutionInputFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/_managed.zip'
   UseDeploymentSettingsFile: true
   DeploymentSettingsFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/settings.json'
   AsyncOperation: true
   MaxAsyncWaitTime: '60'
   OverwriteUnmanagedCustomizations: true

Below exception is thrown during the execution,

Request failed with: Forbidden and error:
{"error":{"code":"ConnectionAuthorizationFailed","message":"The caller
with object id '3c4b71874' does not have the minimum
required permission to perform the requested operation on connection
'ec6e6506238' under API 'shared_uiflow'."}} and request
url
https://api.powerapps.com/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/scopes/service/apis/shared_uiflow/connections/ec66238?api-version=2018-10-01&$expand=permissions($filter=maxAssignedTo('3c41874')&$filter=environment
eq '7e**f50'.

The settings file references the SPO and Desktop connection as below,
"ConnectionReferences": [
    {
      "LogicalName": "contoso_Desktop_Flow_ConnRef",
      "ConnectionId": "9fec************215a9",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_uiflow"
    },
    {
      "LogicalName": "contoso_Microsoft_Dataverse_ConnRef",
      "ConnectionId": "shared-commondataser-c46c-000-000-000-09f",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_commondataserviceforapps"
    },
    {
      "LogicalName": "contoso_SharePoint_ConnRef",
      "ConnectionId": "31ee90000000000000000000553a71d",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_sharepointonline"
    },
    {
      "LogicalName": "new_shareduiflow_45580",
      "ConnectionId": "9fecdd3c-0000-000-000-4b2717a215a9",
      "ConnectorId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_uiflow"
    }
  ]

Note:  We have a reusable pipeline which is working successfully in scenarios where there is no 'desktop connections'.

Can you share more details about the pipeline definition and how to configure the connection in settings file? This will be helpful to investigate the issue further.

How do you create the desktop flow connections?  You can try to refer to the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/alm/alm-connection#get-the-group-id-of-the-machine-or-group to create a connection with service principal and you can give permissions on the machine or machine group.

Thanks.  Yesterday, we were able to deploy the Desktop flow when we created the Desktop connection with the Service principal, now we are facing authentication issue.  Currently, we are looking into this.  Bit of background: Our initial importSolution task had PublishWorkflows set to false, the constraint in sharing the desktop connection meant it was not possible to start these flows.  We suspect the same constraint is leading to the new error.  One question: Why is the Desktop connection made non-shareable, whereas SPO connection is shared?

For the authentication issue,  is this a new error ? Or the error shared in the question?
